# Should I always replace 'const int' with 'constexpr int' in C++11 whenever possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

Would you replace

```
const int one = 1;
const int two = 2;
```

with this?

```
constexpr int one = 1;
constexpr int two = 2;
```

Is my understanding correct that both blocks are semantically identical and that it is currently merely a matter of taste?

On the other hand, as `constexpr` implies `const`, you could argue that it is more consistent to always prefer the more restrictive form, even in trivial situations where it does not make a difference?

(I understand that the situation completely changes when the expression on the right side are allowed to be more complicated. So for clarification, the question only focuses on the most simple case where the expression is a fixed integer number.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you're specifying something like an API, you might decide to use `const int` to store a constant expression as that property might not hold in future revisions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your statement saying that `const` and `constexpr` "*are semantically identical*" should be revised: they both declare objects whose value cannot change, but `constexpr` also requires the initializer expression to be computable at compile-time.

Now if the expression on the right-hand side cannot be computed at compile-time, using `constexpr` is out of the question. On the other hand, as long as the initializer is a literal, you *could* use `constexpr`, but keep into account what the semantics of your variable is: does your constant variable really represent something whose value *should* be computable at compile-time?

In a SW maintenance/evolution optics, it is possible that you will change the way you initialize your variable throughout time: today the initializer is a literal, tomorrow it might be a more complex expression.

Regardless of the way you are assigning it a value *now*, do you think that `i` will ever need to be initialized by anything else than a literal, and that the initializing expression may not be computable at compile-time? If that is the case, then just make your variable `const`, even though you are currently initializing it with a literal; otherwise, make it `constexpr`.

In other words, choose the qualifier that best expresses the semantics of your variable.

Comment: I'd turn that last advice on its head: ask yourself: "Does this name need to be resolved at compile time?" (eg. I use it as an array size or an enum value somewhere.) If so, use `constexpr` so that no-one is tempted to change it in a way which would cause the use of the name to fail.

Comment: @rici: Makes sense, but I think the OP is mostly concerned with the case when the answer to the question in your comment is "no". When the answer is "yes", certainly the variable should be made `constexpr`. But what if the initializer does not strictly need to be a `constexpr` expression, and just happens to be one now? That's the question I tried to answer.

Comment: fair enough, but it seems to me very hard to answer the question "might `i` someday need to be initialized by something more complicated than a literal?", and very easy to answer the question "Does `i` need to be known at compile-time?" Using `constexpr` consistently to indicate the latter provides useful information to the code reader; using `const` to indicate that you imagine a possible contrafactual future, not so much.

Comment: @rici: The thing is, if he even *wanted* to declare `const int i = ...` and then use that as an array size, he just wouldn't be allowed, because the compiler would emit an error. While it is true that "*Using constexpr consistently to indicate the latter provides useful information to the code reader*", you cannot choose to do otherwise. I believe the question is all about those cases where you do have a choice.

Comment: @AndyProwl You are right, I'm interested in the cases where you have the choice. The maintenance argument is a good one, though. Maybe this could serve as a rule of thumb: "Do you want others to write code that requires the variable to be constexpr?" If not, make it only const, otherwise constexpr. According to this rule, I would choose constexpr in my example.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen your rule of thumb's right; "According to this rule, I would choose constexpr in my example" - in your example we have no basis on which to guess what you might want client code to do, although superficially `two = 2` is an identity that it would be insane to change.  More explicitly, a key scenerio where you want to avoid `constexpr` is when you're hardcoding a value now but can see that it might be necessary later to use a value from the command line or a config file, though there are many variations and other scenerios....

Comment: @TonyD: Config file is *exactly* the case I was thinking of.

Comment: There are a number of elements of a really great answer here.  Will somebody take the time to actually make an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to replace `const` with `constexpr` in such case,

```
const int one = 1;
const int two = 2;
```

If you have a constant variable like this,

```
const int three = one + two;
```

you would better to define it as `constexpr`

```
constexpr int three = one + two;
```

to make sure three will be computed during the compilation period.

I know someone would argue, the modern compiler will do the optimizing, to even compute it just with `const`.

I just take an example for the usage of constexpr, the calculation maybe complicated and the compiler couldn't optimize it.