# C++ constexpr error

Tags: c++, undefined, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>  //type_t

constexpr size_t sz = 5; //error here "Identifier constexpr is undefined"

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error at compile time: "Identifier constexpr is undefined." Am I forgeting something? Including something maybe?
It seems like one those stupid things that will make me facepalm when I notice...
I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support `constexpr`.

Comment: what is `constexpr` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Read about [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), especially [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So what do I use to replace it? Just const?

Comment: People have addressed the support constexpr for VS2012 , but till then you'll have to look at the error...

Comment: `const` doesn't carry the same meaning but should be good enough in 99% cases.

Comment: Check this out if u need more clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078689/should-i-always-replace-const-int-with-constexpr-int-in-c11-whenever-possi

Comment: Just a remark about your code: since you're (correctly) including `<cstddef>` (as opposed to `<stddef.h>`) and don't have a `using namespace std;` or `using std::size_t;`, you should rather write `constexpr std::size_t sz = 5;` (you have no guarantee that every compiler will import `size_t` from the namespace `std` into the global namespace).

Comment: Why not just use `const`(in this case)?